# How to use jQuery to access an element in a new browser window?

Tags: jquery, window

Can one refer to an element within a new browser window from the original page using jquery?

```
divOnMainPage = document.createElement(‘div’)

divOnMainPage.id = ”FirstDiv”

document.body.appendChild(divOnMainPage)

// One can refer to this div with javascript as divOnMainPage; or document.getElementById(‘FirstDiv’);   or with jQuery as $(‘#FirstDiv’)[0]  


// But if a new window is launched:
newWindow = window.open('','','width=200, height=200')

divInWindow = newWindow.document.createElement(‘div’)

divInWindow.id = “SecondDiv”

// Can refer to this in javascript from the MainPage console as divInWindow; or newWindow.document.getElementById(‘SecondDiv’);    but how to get it with jQuery?   $(‘#SecondDiv’)[0] does not work.
```

Comment: Please turn off "smart quotes" when posting code to SO.

Comment: `$(newWindow.document).find("#secondDiv")`

Comment: @Barmar's answer is what I was looking forward. I can expand it to capture all the children too, like for example if that secondDiv was a table I could capture all the rows with:  $(newWindow.document).find("#secondDiv tr")

Answer (score 1):

Like this, it is working.

```
var html = '<div id="SecondDiv"></div>';
newWindow.document.body.innerHTML = html;
newWindow.document.getElementById("SecondDiv").innerHTML="test content";
```

If you want to use JQUERY do this:

```
    var html = '<div id="SecondDiv"></div>';
    var jquery_object = jQuery(newWindow.document.body);
    jquery_object.html(html);
    $(jquery_object,"#SecondDiv").html('Hello World');
```